# log4net File is not Getting Created when its deployed in COM object

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I'm trying to integrate log4net dll in one of the project. it works fine when i run it locally.However, when i try to deploy the project as COM Object remotely, it doesn't create any log file at given location. 
FYI, i'm using .net framework 2 for this project

I have made all the changes mentioned on the following link but still no luck

1. [Log4net does not write the log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618380/log4net-does-not-write-the-log-file)
2. [Log4net Not Creating Log File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151444/log4net-not-creating-log-file)

**AssesmblyInfo.cs**

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "app.config", Watch = true)]
```

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="TestAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:\\log\\SchT%date{yyyyMMdd}.log" />
      <encoding value="utf-8"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <!--<rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />-->
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level [%thread] %type.%method - %message%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="All"/>
      <!-- If the following line is not included the log file will not be created even if log4net is configured with this file. -->
      <appender-ref ref="TestAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>

  <startup>

    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

**Controller**

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
           _log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
    (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

**When i debug it, _log gets all log levels as false. I suspect, app.config doesn't load properly that's why file is not created.**

Any idea?

Comment: _"when i try to deploy the project as COM Object remotely"_ - can you give more details about that?

Comment: It's probably looking for app.config in the base directory of the AppDomain that hosts log4net.  If this is a COM object, the base directory is likely to be the directory where the unmanaged executable that loads the COM object is located.  Try examining AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory when you're debugging.

Comment: Thanks Joe. It works.